# Creating a single dictionary from two tab delimited files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I'm somewhat new to Python and still trying to learn all its tricks and exploitations.
I'm looking to see if it's possible to collect column data from two separate files to create a single dictionary, rather than two distinct dictionaries. The code that I've used to import files before looks like this:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')   
    for row in reader:
        for (header,variable) in row.items():
            columns[header].append(variable)           
f.close()
```

This code makes each element of the first line of the file into a header for the columns of data below it. What I'd like to do now is to import a file that only contains one line which I'll use as my header, and import another file that only contains data that I'll match the headers up to. What I've tried so far resembles this:

```
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open("headerData.txt") as g:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(g,delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader1:
        for (h,v) in row.items():
            columns[h].append(v)

    with open("variableData.txt") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')   
        for row in reader:
            for (h,v) in row.items():
                columns[h].append(v)
```

Is nesting the open statements the right way to attempt this? Honestly I am totally lost on what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `with` statements don't need to be nested; you're done reading from `headerData.txt` by the time you open `variableData.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `DictReader` like that if the headers are not in the file. But you can create a fake file object that would yield the headers and then the data, using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
with open('headerData.txt') as h, open('variableData.txt') as data:
    f = chain(h, data)
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')
    # proceed with you code from the first snippet

# no close() calls needed when using open() with "with" statements
```

Another way of course would be to just read the headers into a list and use regular `csv.reader` on `variableData.txt`:

```
with open('headerData') as h:
    names = next(h).split('\t')
with open('variableData.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        for name, value in zip(names, row):
            columns[name].append(value)
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked perfectly, thanks! How would you change your code if the two files you're importing have different delimiters, seeing as how the delimiter in DictReader is specified as one specific instance? Just curious.

Comment: @user3555455 In that case it doesn't make sense to read them as a single file. I'd use the second way then, or the on from dano's answer.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `DictReader` will take the first line in your csv file and use that as the keys for the dict. However, according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), you can also pass it a `fieldnames` parameter, which is a sequence containing the names of the keys to use for the dict. So you could do this:

```
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open("headerData.txt") as f, open("variableData.txt") as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data, 
                            fieldnames=f.read().rstrip().split('\t'), 
                            delimiter='\t')   
    for row in reader:
        for (h,v) in row.items():
            columns[h].append(v)
```

Comment: +1, if I had read the docs before answering, I'd go with this option.